# Extending CMake with a custom generator?

Tags: cmake

How would one add support for a new IDE/build system to CMake? Does it provide a mechanism to do this without modifying its code directly?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to write additional C++ code and build CMake to add a new generator. There is no mechanism to add a new generator without writing new code.

What IDE/build system are you thinking of adding to CMake?

Ask on the CMake mailing list ( http://www.cmake.org/mailman/listinfo/cmake ) whether or not anybody else is already working on a generator for the system you're thinking of. I know some recent work has been done to add a Ninja generator... It is not yet in the official CMake release, though: still in progress as of today.

Comment: Thanks. It's actually for a custom, special-purpose IDE I'm developing for my own use.